# You must provide a value expression following the '%' operator

Tags: powershell, imagemagick

```
PS C:\ImageMagick> convert -background transparent -fill hsb(0%,0%,0%) -font Arial -pointsize 18 -size 18x26 -gravity center label:p "output2.png"
At line:1 char:51
+ convert -background transparent -fill hsb(0%,0%,0%) -font Arial -pointsize 18 -s ...
+                                                   ~
You must provide a value expression following the '%' operator.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

The command above which works without any trouble in a cmd window is throwing an error coming out in red text in PowerShell, which I have pasted above. I looked at a number of articles but have not come up with a good solution yet.

I though perhaps they were talking about the call to `hsb` which I surrounded in quotations:

```
PS C:\ImageMagick> convert -background transparent -fill "hsb(0%,0%,0%)" -font Arial -pointsize 18 -size 18x26 -gravity center label:p "output2.png"
Invalid Parameter - transparent
```

that just leads to a different problem. I have tried prefixing the command with `&`, which is a technique I had been previously unfamiliar but that did not seem to solve anything.

Comment: To fix your problem, you could simply omit the "%" sign: 0% = 0; 100% = 255. "%" is the modulo operator in powershell. You could also quote the full line and "dot source" it (i.e.: . "convert ....").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PowerShell does not use current directory as palace for looking for commands. So `convert` is resolved to `C:\Windows\System32\convert.exe`

```
Get-Command convert|ft CommandType,Name,Definition

# CommandType Name        Definition
# ----------- ----        ----------
# Application convert.exe C:\Windows\System32\convert.exe
```

If you want to invoke `convert.exe` from current directory use `.\convert` instead of `convert`.

Comment: That is not the first issue the OP is hitting but it will be his second.  :-)  Good catch.

Answer (score 4):

PowerShell is interpreting the parens as a grouping expression so it thinks the % inside is the remainder (modulus) operator.  You can get PowerShell to parse in kind of a 'dumb' mode with the stop parsing operator `--%` e.g.:

```
convert.exe --% -background transparent -fill hsb(0%,0%,0%) -font Arial -pointsize 18 -size 18x26 -gravity center label:p "output2.png"
```